# SQL Server BAK file opens in Notepad

Tags: sql-server, backup, notepad

I have a SQL Server `.BAK` file but it opens in Notepad. How can I change it into a `.bak` format?

Comment: Is it or isn't it a .bak file? You cannot open a backup file directly, you need sql server to restore it before you can use it.

Comment: It is .bak file but displays a notepad. Under properties, it says "opens with notepad". Can I restore such files using SSMS?

Comment: You can *only* restore such files using sql server (you can use SSMS, which is just a UI for sql server).

Comment: Try right click "Open with" -> "Choose default program...". Make sure "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" is checked. It's no programming related question however and is better placed on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: When I try to restore from the .BAK file where it says "opens with Notepad", I get the following error "Cannot open backup device. 'L:\...' Operating System error 2 (the system cannot find the file specified)". But when I restore from a clear .BAK file saying noting about opens with notepad, the restore process works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a '.bak' extension then is is already a 'bak' file, and SQL Server will be able to open it. What you are referring to is your default option for opening files of '.bak' type, which you can change by right clicking the file, going to 'Open with' and then choosing whatever program you would like.

However, there is likely no need to change this, as only SSMS can open and use the file anyway.

Comment: You need sql server, you don't need SSMS as it's only a UI. It seems nitpicking, but there's a clear distinction.

Comment: When I try to restore from the .BAK file where it says "opens with Notepad", I get the following error "Cannot open backup device. 'L:\...' Operating System error 2 (the system cannot find the file specified)". But when I restore from a clear .BAK file saying noting about opens with notepad, the restore process works fine.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between these two files. Do they or do they not both have the file extension '.bat'? If you are not clicking 'save' after you open in notepad, or altering the file extension, I wouldn't expect them to behave any differently (in fact, they shouldn't both be able to exist with the same name in the same place, as they should be identical).